# Are these $L^{p,q}$ Lebesgue spaces?

Tags: distribution-theory

I have a theorem, deduced mostly from Loukas' Classical Fourier Analysis book 2009:

> Let $(X,\mu)$ be a measure space.
>       Then for all $0 <p,q \leq \infty$, the Lebesgue spaces $L^{p,q}(X,\mu)$ over the measure space $(X,\mu)$ are complete with
>   respect to their quasinorm  and they are therefore quasi-Banach
>   spaces.

**Can you call $L^{p,q}$ Lebesgue spaces?**

If you choose $p = 4, q = 4$. **Can you call $L^{4,4}$ Lebesgue space?**

I do not want to confuse the reader with Lorentz spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that $L^{p,p}=L^{p}$, so when $q=p$, they are Lebesgue spaces.

When $p\neq q$, they are merely Lorentz spaces.

Comment: Would it be better the word Lorentz spaces in the theorem, instead of Lebesgue spaces, when we do not know about the values of p and q? They can be different or equal.

Comment: Or leave both words out from the theorem, since we do not want to specify if $p=q$ xor $p \not= q$.

Comment: @Masi Call them Lorentz spaces. A Lebesgue space is also a Lorentz space, so you do not make an error by calling them Lorentz spaces. The statement you have right now is not correct, because the spaces are not always Lebesgue spaces.